# PHP Count Rows In Oracle Database

Tags: php, sql, oracle, select

I am trying to count the total number of rows in a single table. Just need to know how many rows total and nothing else. I am using Oracle database.

I have tried

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS homes FROM homes";
```

But I am unsure on how to display the result.

Comment: Where is the rest of the code?

Comment: how do you send the SQL command to the database? you should show that as well, perhaps you're not using the correct function.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM homes";
```

Comment: Without an explanation I doubt this would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

    $link = mysqli_connect("host", "username", "password");
    mysqli_select_db("database", $link);

    $result = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM homes", $link);
    $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    echo "$num_rows Rows\n";

?>
```

Comment: How do you know OP is using `mysql`?

Comment: Also, the PHP mysql extension is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

To count the rows from

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM homes";  // fetch the rows
 $sql1=mysql_query($sql);
 $count=mysql_num_rows($sql1)  // count number of rows in table
 echo $count;  //$count has the value of rows in table..
```

Comment: How do you know OP is using `mysql`?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

// Code goes here

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS homes FROM homes";
$result = mysqli_query($sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
print($row['homes']); // prints count
?>
```

Comment: How do you know OP is using `mysqli`?